# expected ';' after expression

Tags: c++, factory

I'm trying to port a project from Windows to Mac. I'm having troubles compiling the class CFactory. I'll try to illustrate the problem.

Here's what I have on my **Factory.h**

```
namespace BaseSubsystems
{
    template <class T>
    class CFactory
    {
    protected:
        typedef T (*FunctionPointer)();
        typedef std::pair<std::string,FunctionPointer> TStringFunctionPointerPair;
        typedef std::map<std::string,FunctionPointer> TFunctionPointerMap;
        TFunctionPointerMap _table;
    public:
        CFactory () {}
        virtual ~CFactory();
    }; // class CFactory

    template <class T> 
    inline CFactory<T>::~CFactory()
    {
        TFunctionPointerMap::const_iterator it = _table.begin();
        TFunctionPointerMap::const_iterator it2;

        while( it != _table.end() )
        {
            it2 = it;
            it++;
            _table.erase(it2);
        }

    } // ~CFactory
}
```

When I'm trying to compile, the compiler complains:

```
Factory.h:95:44: error: expected ';' after expression [1]
         TFunctionPointerMap::const_iterator it = _table.begin();
                                            ^
                                            ;
```

Why is this happening? That am I missing?

NOTE: This project compiles properly on MSVC.

Thanks.

Comment: [Needs more `typename`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Sorry but, why do you actually mean by that? Thanks.

Comment: `typename TFunctionPointerMap::const_iterator` should fix it. See the link I posted for all the gritty details.

Comment: Can you check if it makes a difference when you replace TFunctionPointerMap with the structure it is typedeffing (i.e. std::map<std::string, FunctionPointer>)?

Comment: It does. Thanks. I'll take a look at the document. Really helpful tip

Comment: Very enlightening response my R. Martinho Fernandes.  Thanks!

Comment: Btw now it complains about `_table.erase(it2)`, it says `no matching member function for call to 'erase'`, any tip for that? I'm really a beginner about such advanced details of C++

Comment: @frarees: it's probably best to open a new question.

Comment: Ok I'm going to. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the required `typename` keyword when referring to a dependent type. Microsoft Visual Studio incorrectly accepts your code without the `typename` (this is a well known mistake in VS that will never be corrected).

```
typename TFunctionPointerMap::const_iterator it;
```